# Query with GROUP BY and ORDER BY not working when multiple columns in SELECT are chosen

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I'm updating an old website and one of the queries isn't working anymore:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY col2
```

I noticed if I dropped the `GROUP BY` it works, but the result set doesn't match the original:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL ORDER BY col2
```

So I tried reading up on `GROUP BY` in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to see what might be the issue, and it seemed to suggest not using `*` to select all the fields, but explicitly using the column name so I tried it with just the column that was being ordered and grouped:

```
SELECT col2 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY col2
```

Which works but after looking through the code the query requires 2 columns in the query so whoever added `*` was overdoing it, but if I add that column produces an error, similarly adding a third column produces the same error:

```
SELECT col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY col2
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY col2
```

Can anyone tell me why this last query doesn't work?  I can't decipher why from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), but this is the minimum query required to get the result set I need.

Running the query in Adminer I get this error

```
Error in query (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY 
clause and contains nonaggregated column 'name.table.column' 
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is 
incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you are trying to order by a column that you are not selecting. It should like it should be possible but is not always doable. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34951/order-by-clause-is-allowed-over-column-that-is-not-in-select-list

Comment: I just get an error trying to invoke  `$conn->fetchAll()` which says `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll`, since `$dbConn->query($sql);` returns false

Comment: @mtpultz that is a different question all together. the current question is an SQL question, not a PHP question

Comment: Try to run it in the database directly so it might give a more detailed error message. Unless some of the answers help.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" please be more descriptive. Was there an error? Is the result set empty? Is the result not what you expected?

Comment: Try to add col1 in the select and see if that works. Seems like an edge case so will help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Posted the error from Adminer.  Adding more columns to the select produces the same error.  Also fixed a typo in the SQL query

Comment: Why do you need a `GROUP BY` if you have no aggregated columns and already have an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @digital.aaron not my choice this is stage one to an upgrade to a 15 year old PHP delimited spaghetti coded site so this is a line-by-line effort to make it work using a more recent server instead of MySQL 3.x and PHP 4.x using MySQL 5.7 and PHP 7.x so the deprecations and changes are overwhelming I'm just trying to get it all working as fast as possible

Comment: To make it easier to get it all working, you need to learn how to analyze errors much better. For example, you've got a `tail -f` going on the http error log, right? You know how to use [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) and [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)? You know to *NEVER* use `@` to suppress errors?

Comment: A simple way to solve non aggregated columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when `query()` returns false, you should find out what the error was. You seem to be using PDO, so I will direct you to this page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

TL;DR - you should enable PDO exceptions, or else you need to write code to check the result of every call to `query()`, `prepare()`, and `execute()` to see if an error occurred. And if so, use `errorInfo()` to find out the actual error. Doing anything else is flying blind!

> Error in query (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY 
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'webvictoria.cats_oct.matchLink' 
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is 
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This is a common issue. See dozens of questions tagged [mysql-error-1055](/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1055).

I guess you just upgraded to MySQL 5.7. MySQL 5.7 enabled strict mode by default, so I guess you just upgraded. Prior to MySQL 5.6, strict mode was optional and not enabled by default.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

You can't write ambiguous queries. If you `GROUP BY col2`, which value in the group of rows of each group should be used for col1 and col3? It's ambiguous.

Without strict mode, MySQL chooses an arbitrary row from the group. With strict mode, it reverts to standard SQL behavior, and disallows the ambiguous query. This is how most other brands of SQL database behave, by the way.

To fix it, you must follow this rule: Every column in your select list must be one of:

- A column in your GROUP BY clause
- A column functionally dependent on the columns in your GROUP BY clause (so there can only be one value)
- Used in an aggregate function like MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), SUM(), AVG(), or GROUP_CONCAT()

Some people choose to disable strict mode in MySQL 5.7 for the sake of "getting the code working again." But it *isn't* working—it's just giving ambiguous results like it did before MySQL 5.7.

It's better to fix the logic of your queries.

Comment: Thanks that's a great explanation and advice.  Using your rules I was able to get this to work

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful when you use `GROUP BY`. Once you understand what `GROUP BY` does, you will know the issue yourself. It does an aggregation on your data or in other words, it reduces your data by doing some operation on the raw entries and creating new reduced number of entries on which some aggregation function has been applied(SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc.)

The fields you provide in the `GROUP BY` clause represents the level of aggregation/roll-up you are going for.

```
SELECT col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY col1
```

Here you are trying to do the aggregation at `col1` level, meaning that for every distinct value present in column `col1`, there will be some operation done on some other columns you provide in `SELECT` clause(here `col2`,`col3`) so that in the output you have non-repeating values in `col1` and some rolled-up values of `col2` and `col3` against each distinct `col1` value based on what function you apply(SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc.).

How do you apply this function? That is what is missing in your above query. To solve it, you need to apply some aggregation function on the fields that are present in the `SELECT` clause but not in `GROUP BY` clause. Taking an example of SUM, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(col2), SUM(col3) FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY col1
```

OR for a better idea, removing `WHERE` filter and checking the output by running:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2), SUM(col3) FROM tbl GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY col1
```

Additionally, the reason why your other query

```
SELECT col2 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY col2
```

worked is because you need not apply aggregation to the field(here `col2`) which is present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE col1 IS NULL
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1;
```

never really worked.  It may have *seemed to* work, but you were just lucky.  You have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  These come from an *arbitrary* row.

You *can* do something like this to get values from other columns:

```
SELECT col1, min(col2), min(col3)
FROM tbl t
WHERE col1 IS NULL AND
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is because you need to use one of the selection criteria in the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY`. So if you wanted to group by col1, you would need to do this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3     
   FROM tbl     
   WHERE 
      col1 IS NULL     
   GROUP BY col1     
   ORDER BY col1 
;
```

Without selecting that field, you are basically saying "Hey go get me every phone number in California" Then after you get that you say "Now order them by first name and group them by last name" and DBMS says "but... I don't have any of that"

Comment: I am not sure if that is required. The columns are not selected but they are still available in the table to it should be possible to order by a column that you are not selecting. Not sure about group by though.

Comment: How would be able to group something you didn't select? you would have no idea how they were actually grouped. Same with order by.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT col2, col3 FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NULL GROUP BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col2, col3
```

Comment: I think the idea is to group by col1 and order by col1.

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   Please describe what your code is doing and how it solves the problem.