# How to fix query group with only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1055

I have a basic key-value table, that has some data in it for each user. With the updated mysql it has the `sql_mode` set to `only_full_group_by` (new default) when you do a group by. When I try to run this simple query:

```
select * from user_features
where user_id = 1
group by feature_key
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error (1055): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'date.user_features.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

With this example data, I want to group based on the `feature_key` (I will add a `group_concat` once the group error is fixed).

```
| user_id | feature_key | feature_value |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| 1       | color       | red           |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| 1       | age         | 15            |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| 1       | color       | blue          |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_features` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feature_key` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `feature_value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_feature_key_feature_value` (`user_id`,`feature_key`,`feature_value`)
)
```

What query can I run to fix this or what index(es) do I need to add?

Comment: So answer this previously when you do group by which value you get for key color ? red or blue ?

Comment: Are you asking what color I get without the group? Not quite sure I understand the question. Sorry.

Comment: With the previous version of mysql that is < 5.7 which value you get for color and now with newer version which value you expect to return, This group by behavior is normal and Mysql has adopted this too late as compared to other RDBMS

Comment: I have no idea, I just know that that would be a valid query in older versions of mysql and return a row (I believe that red would be populated).

Comment: What you believe like for red, there has to be some reason or criteria to select the row which has red color or otherwise limit your unique index to user_id and feature key so that for each user there cannot be 2 same feature keys

Comment: Oh wow... All I had to do was change the `select` from `*` to `user_id, feature_key, group_concat(feature_value)`

Comment: That is the difference you used an aggregate function but it still it give you 2 values per feature and user that red and blue not only red

Comment: So, basically it didn't know what to do with that second value. Is that about right?

Comment: [As per docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) *SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common error for MySQL users. In MySQL 5.7, by default the database enforces the standard semantics that most other SQL databases have been enforcing for years.

The rule is that every column in your select-list must be one of:

- Named in the GROUP BY clause; i.e. it's what you are grouping be.
- Inside an aggregate function like MIN, MAX(), SUM(), GROUP_CONCAT(), etc.
- Functionally dependent on the column you are grouping by (this is MySQL's extension to standard SQL behavior, and other SQL databases don't necessarily support this).

In your query (I'll expand your `SELECT *`):

```
select user_id, feature_key, feature_value from user_features
where user_id = 1
group by feature_key
```

You are grouping by feature_key, but this means the other columns don't comply with the rules I described above.

Here's a way to fix it:

```
select MAX(user_id), feature_key, GROUP_CONCAT(feature_value)
from user_features
where user_id = 1
group by feature_key
```

It might seem redundant to use `MAX(user_id)` since there is only one value possible based on the WHERE clause condition. But there's no harm either. `MIN(user_id)` would also work.

See also my past answers on this same error:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47701851/20860
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705647/20860